# I am trying to pass a Json response as an attribute to custom component, how to handle the response in custom component in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have custom tag in `header.component.ts` as below `<app-jjviewer [json]=data.response></app-jjviewer>` and I am passing response as json attribute.

I have jjsonviewer.component.ts where I have @component with selector as 'app-jjviewer'

How can I use the data of json attribute in my j`jsonviewer.component.ts`? How can I get the data? If I use console.log how to print it?

I need to pass the data to the below function in jjsonviewer.component.ts 
 `$(this.el.nativeElement).jJsonViewer(this.json, {expanded: true});`

Angular 4

Comment: <app-jjviewer [json]=data.response></app-jjviewer>